# Perl Largest,Smallest,Average of numbers using Subroutines

Tags: perl

My question in Perl:
Write a Perl Script with a subroutine that accepts a list of values and returns the largest,smallest and average values to the calling program.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub large_and_small {   
    my (@numbers);
    @numbers = @_;

    my ($small, $large);
    $large = $numbers[0];
    $small = $numbers[0];

    foreach my $i (@numbers) {

        if ($i > $large) {         

            $large = $i;  
        }        
        elsif ($i < $small) {

            $small = $i;  
        }
    }
    return ($small, $large);
}

sub avg {
    my ($avg);
    my ($total);

    foreach (@test_array) {

        $total += $_;
    }
    $avg = $total/scalar @test_array;
    return $avg;
}

my (@test_array, @ret);
@test_array = (15, 5, 7, 3, 9, 1, 20,1 3, 9, 8, 15, 16, 2, 6, 12, 90);
@ret = large_and_small(@test_array);
print "The Largest value is ", $ret[1], "\n";
print "The Smallest value is ", $ret[0], "\n";
print "The Average value is", avg(@test_array), "\n";
```

The Output I am getting is:

```
The Largest value is 90
The Smallest value is 1
Illegal division by zero at /tmp/135044395416028.pl line 59.
```

Where am I going wrong in the script? Please help.Thanks in advance

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

avg procedure does not see `@test_array` that you think it should see.
Instead, it likely sees empty array.

Rewrite `avg` as follows and it should work:

```
sub avg {
    my @test_array = @_;
    my ($avg);
    my ($total);
    # ...
}
```

Comment: Kinda silly to copy `@_`. Just use `for (@_)` instead of `for (@test_array)`.

Comment: Well, it is not really that silly. Granted, it is not efficient. But, for humans readability is much more important. And this is exactly why it is there for.

Comment: You're saying `@test_array` is more meaningful than `@_` in a function that averages arbitrary numbers?

Answer (score 4):

I advice you use core module: `List::Util`, it has all functions, that you implemented as min, max, sum.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use List::Util qw(min max sum);

my @test_array = (15, 5, 7, 3, 9, 1, 20, 13, 9, 8, 15, 16, 2, 6, 12, 90);
my $min = min(@test_array);
my $max = max(@test_array);
my $avg = scalar @test_array
        ? (sum(@test_array) / (scalar @test_array))
        : 0;

print "The Largest value is ", $max, "\n";
print "The Smallest value is ", $min, "\n";
print "The Average value is ", $avg, "\n";
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 3):

You are not reading the arguments in `avg`. Add

```
my @test_array = @_;
```

You can also save some variables and do declarations and assignments at the same time:

```
sub large_and_small {
    my @numbers = @_;
    my ($small, $large) = @numbers[0, 0];

    foreach my $n (@numbers) {
        if ($n > $large) {
            $large = $n;
        }
        elsif ($n < $small) {
            $small = $n;
        }
    }
    return ($small, $large);
}

sub avg {
    my @numbers = @_;
    return unless @numbers;  # Prevent Division by zero
    my $total;
    foreach (@numbers) {
        $total += $_;
    }
    return $total / @numbers;
}
```

Comment: @user1613245 Then you can accept one of the answers by clicking the arrow besides the answers.

Answer (score 0):

The test array is declared as lexical in the main, and used directly in the function. Either it has to be passed to the function, or remove the lexical which is not advised.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like there's divisionby zero here

```
$avg = $total/scalar @test_array;
```

Why are you dividing by scalar?

Comment: `scalar @array` returns the number of elements of the array.

Comment: The expression is correct. The only problem is that there is no protection against an empty parameter list.